# Difference between I see and I understand

Tags: phrases, expressions, differences

What's the difference between "I see" and "I understand" ?

Comment: Nothing. Or a whole lot. Depends on context.

Comment: **I see** doesn't have the same connotation of agreement as **I understand**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*See* can be used figuratively to mean *understand*. One of [Merriam-Webster's definitions](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/see) of *see* is "to perceive the meaning or importance of : understand" (definition 3b).

For example, if someone explains something to you and you say, "I see," you mean that you understand the explanation. Some other common phrases are "I see your point" to mean "I understand your point" and "Do you see what I'm saying?" to mean "Do you understand what I'm saying?"

Comment: This is the `Seeing Is Knowing` metaphor theme. We trust vision, and eyewitness testimony (notice, **not** "earwitness" -- significantly, "hearsay testimony" is barred in court) more than other sense modalities, even though visual memory is as fallible and suggestible as aural. But vision is a very rich sensory system, with enormous bandwidth, lots of details, and loads of words for them. Compare this situation with smell, for instance, which is largely unconscious in function and has almost no linguistic representation.

Comment: Just curious, how did you get the "Seeing Is Knowing" text to look different in your comment?

Comment: You put a backquote **`** on either side. This is what's called "preformatted text <pre> <code> Ctrl-K" in the editing box; it is marked by curly brackets **{ }** in the command line there.

Comment: `Good to know.`

Comment: `I get it`. It workes as well.